# Azure site deployment with Git without credentials

Tags: git, azure, deployment, git-push

I have a windows Azure site. Currently I deploy the code to Azure using GIT source control tool. It asks me the credentials every time. Is there anyway to push the code without entering the password? We can add the SSH key in Github, Git Stash and access the Git repo directly. I need something like that. Can we do it on Azure site? Can anyone please tell me?

git push azure-site master

Password for 'https://admindev@azure-site.scm.azurewebsites.net:443':

Comment: This might answer your question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8cc45066-8976-4635-a431-6b8986867776/possible-to-use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate-with-git-server

Comment: Thank you..It seems Windows Azure has Continuous Deployment feature from GitHub/BitBucket. But I use Atlassian Stash as my Git repo :(

Comment: Is there an update about this? I use a local git repo for continuous Deployment and want to avoid bein asked for my password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is .gitcredentials or netrc file. this file can be created in user home path. It stores the https credentials. from the next time it won't prompt for password. 
[Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)